# What is the true status of the Lehmer totient problem?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, reference-request, totient-function, open-problem

The Lehmer-totient problem : For a prime number $\ n\ $ we have $\ \varphi(n)=n-1\ $. In particular, we have $\ \varphi(n) \mid n-1\ $. Is there a composite number $\ n\ $  with $\ \varphi(n)\mid n-1\ $ ?

It can easily be shown that such a number must be a Carmichael number.

> What is the real status of this problem ?

I found some pages in the internet claiming a proof, but neither Wikipedia nor Mathworld consider this
problem to be solved. The best lower bound is claimed to be $10^{22}$ in Mathworld, but Wikipedia still gives $10^{20}$ as the best bound. Which is true ? And is the problem solved or not ?

Comment: besides some claimed proofs I also found an entry claiming $\omega(n)\ge 15$ and $n\ge 10^{30}$ which would be much better than the $10^{22}$ in Mathworld.

Comment: To avoid duplication of effort it would help Readers to attribute the "claimed proofs" and "entry claiming ...".

Comment: Glad you made this thread. I wondered the same a couple of weeks ago. Some person added three separate lines on the Wikipedia page of the Lehmer totient problem claiming to have solved the problem (apparently it's "in press") but since I could not find the paper anywhere, I removed those lines from the article. Considering this is about math research though, it might be a better fit for MathOverflow.

Comment: @Peter What are the different generalizations of LTP? I am running some experiment with $\varphi(n) | n-k$ for odd $k$, and data suggests that for any odd $k$ there are at most a finite number of solutions.

Comment: @NilotpalKantiSinha This would be an interesting question. You can summarize your observations and ask whether there are heuristics for the truth of this generalization.

Comment: @Peter: Posted it here. Apparently is an old conjecture of Ronald Graham. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3772038/for-which-odd-number-k-does-varphin-mid-n-k-has-infinitely-many-sol/3772078#3772078

Comment: @Peter:  Please check out my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick search through arXiv yields the following results:

> **(1)** This proof for the Lehmer-totient problem has been withdrawn:

> > [On the Lehmer's problem involving Euler's totient function (Huan Xiao)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.08313)

> **(2)** I highly doubt the validity of the following proof, although it is not yet withdrawn:

> > [An analytical proof for Lehmer's totient conjecture using Mertens' theorems (Ahmad Sabihi)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.08086)

Regarding the lower bounds for $n$ and $\omega(n)$ when $\varphi(n) \mid (n-1)$, I quote from the [MathWorld website](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LehmersTotientProblem.html):

> The best current result is $n > {10}^{22}$ and $\omega(n) \geq 14$, improving the ${10}^{20}$ lower bound of Cohen and Hagis (1980) - "On the Number of Prime Factors of $n$ is $\varphi(n) \mid (n-1)$", since there are no Carmichael numbers less than ${10}^{22}$ having $\geq 14$ distinct prime factors (Pinch).

When $3 \mid n$, then it is known that
$$\omega(n) \geq 40000000$$
and
$$n > {10}^{360000000}$$
by [computational work](http://ac.inf.elte.hu/Vol_035_2011/043.pdf) of P. Burcsi, S. Czirbusz, and G. Farkas (2011).

Comment: But why does Wikipedia not mention this improvement ?

Comment: Apparently, Wikipedia does not mention this improvement because the result can be *implicitly mined* from Pinch's FTP tables.

Comment: OK, so $10^{22}$ is correct and there is no proof , right ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, @Peter.

Comment: OK, Thank you. (+1 and accept)

Comment: I read Sabihi's paper. The proofs rest on the assertion that the equation α/(e^γ log(p_k)) = 1/(p_1 *...* p_k) cannot have any solutions, where α is the fractional part of e^γ log(p_k), since the denominator p_1 * ... * p_k is much larger than e^γ log(p_k). (γ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant, and the p_i are primes). However, since α is less than one, this is not true.